# Validating checkboxes using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having difficulty validating a group of radio buttons, this is the code I'm using right now but I keep getting the error message: `Runtime error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method`.

This is the code that is causing the problem.

```
For Each ctl In Me.frPriority.Controls
        If ctl.Value = True Then GoTo nxtCheck1
    Next
        MsgBox "You didn't select a priority"
    Exit Sub
nxtCheck1:
```

The line causing all the trouble is

```
If ctl.Value = True Then
```

How can I resole this problem?

Comment: Are there controls other than radio buttons in `frPriority`? You need to check the control type in your loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have non-option buttons control types in your frame, use this, checking for the control type first.

```
For Each ctl In Me.frPriority.Controls
    If TypeOf ctl Is msforms.OptionButton Then
        If ctl.Value = True Then GoTo nxtCheck1
    end if 
Next
        MsgBox "You didn't select a priority"
    Exit Sub
nxtCheck1:
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you're looping through all the controls and some of your controls won't have a Value property.

try something like this:

```
For Each ctl In Me.frPriority.Controls
   If TypeOf ctl Is msforms.OptionButton Then
        If ctl.Value = True Then GoTo nxtCheck1
   End if
Next
```